# converting code from Tkinter TEXT to Tkinter LABEL

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I want the received data to be centered on tk window instead of printing from top.So I want to write code using Label widget instad of TEXT  widget.(TEXT widget print from top and LABEL widget centers the data on tk window) Label widget has 'ANCHOR' options controls where the text is positioned if the widget has more space than the text needs. The default is anchor=CENTER, which centers the text in the available space.
But in my code i always delete and insert data all the time,according to my knowledge delete and insert options are only in Text widget, is it possible in Label widget.
please help me out.
 I tried to change my code bt using LABEL widget, but couls not succeed. can some one please help me to change my code to use label widget.
thanks.

```
import serial
import threading
import Queue
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class SerialThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        s = serial.Serial('COM11',9600)

        while True:
            if s.inWaiting():
                text = s.readline(s.inWaiting())
                self.queue.put(text)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("1360x750")
        frameLabel = tk.Frame(self, padx=40, pady =40)
        self.text = tk.Text(frameLabel, wrap='word', font='TimesNewRoman 40',
                        bg=self.cget('bg'), relief='flat')
        frameLabel.pack()
        self.text.pack()
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        thread = SerialThread(self.queue)
        thread.start()
        self.process_serial()

    def process_serial(self):
        firstitem = True
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                new = self.queue.get()
                if firstitem:
                    self.text.delete(1.0, 'end')
                firstitem = False
                self.text.insert('end', new)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
        self.after(100, self.process_serial)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tkinter Label widget has a `text` option to indicate the text that is being displayed. If you want to change all the content that the widget displays, then replace

```
self.text = tk.Text(frameLabel, ...)

# ...

new = self.queue.get()     
self.text.delete(1.0, 'end')
self.text.insert('end', new)
```

With this:

```
self.label = tk.Label(frameLabel, ...)

# ...

new = self.queue.get()     
self.label.config(text=new)
```

Comment: I am facing this kind of error.     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/python/New folder/testing 1.py", line 44, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "C:/Python27/python/New folder/testing 1.py", line 26, in __init__
    bg=self.cget('bg'), relief='flat')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2537, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2036, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: bad screen distance "word"

Comment: @vaasu That happens because you are using the option `wrap='word'` in the constructor of the label. If you replace a Text with a Label, you should use the [correct options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method), which vary from widget to widget.

Comment: @ Rodas: I changed the widget options and Its working now. but how can i implement this in label widget. def process_serial(self):
        firstitem = True
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                new = self.queue.get()
                if firstitem:
                    self.text.delete(1.0, 'end')
                firstitem = False
                self.text.insert('end', new)

Comment: it is only showing the last element in the
queue; how  to handle multiple queue items.

Comment: @vaasu That happens because you are deleting the content of the widget after you insert a new item: `self.text.delete(1.0, 'end')`. Just remove this line and it will show all the items.

Comment: Even though i removed (delete and insert)Still only the last elements are displaying. while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                new = self.queue.get()
                self.label.config(text=new)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

Comment: @vaasu In your last example, you were using a Text widget (self.text), but for a Label widget the solution is different. What you can use is `self.label['text'] += new` to append each item to the displayed text.

Comment: @Rodas: Its working but how can I delete the previous content, before displaying another data. here previous data is still displaying, the other data which is received is continuing after the previous received data.

Comment: @Rodas: Is it possible to delete previous content from the window, when i receive a new data for display on window.

Comment: @vaasu That is what does my initial answer: Updates the content that is displayed in the widget and it does not show the previous items.

Comment: @Rodas: This is what i done, even though the previous data on the window is not vanishing.                                                def process_serial(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                new = self.queue.get()
                self.label['text'] +=new
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass    
        self.after(1000, self.process_serial)